# How to pass the Drop down value as an input to a filter function in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr

- Intention : To display a table which is controled by user.
- Input : Type of Clarity in diamonds.
- Input Source : DropDown Menu.

  ```
  library(shiny)
  library(ggplot2)
  require(scales)
  library(dplyr)


  ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(

      sidebarPanel(

        selectInput(inputId = "clarity", 
                    label = "choose a clarity in Diamonds", 
                    choices = c("IF", "VVS1", "VVS2","VS1", "VS2", "SI1","SI2"," I1"," Please Select a Type "),
                    selected = " Please Select a Type " ),
        actionButton(inputId = "action1", label = "action1")

      ),
      mainPanel(

        tableOutput("view")

      ))

  )

  server <- function(input, output){

    #"IF", "VVS1", "VVS2","VS1", "VS2", "SI1","SI2"," I1"," Please Select a Type ")

    datasetInput <- reactive({ 
      switch(input$clarity, 
             "IF" = IF, 
             "VVS1" = VVSI, 
             "VVS2" = VVS2,
             "VS1" = VS1, 
             "VS2" = VS2, 
             "SI1" = SI1,
             "SI2" = SI2, 
             "I1" = I1, 
             " Please Select a Type " = NULL) 
    }) 
    output$view <- eventReactive(input$action1,{ 
      filter(diamonds, diamonds$clarity == datasetInput()) 
    }) 

  }

  shinyApp(ui = ui , server = server)
  ```

The above code is giving me an error which says

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:4090
Warning: Error in filter_impl: Evaluation error: object 'VVS2' not found.
Stack trace (innermost first):
    103: <Anonymous>
    102: stop
    101: filter_impl
    100: filter.tbl_df
     99: filter
     98: eventReactiveHandler [#21]
     78: output$view
      4: <Anonymous>
      3: do.call
      2: print.shiny.appobj
      1: <Promise>
```

As per my analysis when I am trying to the run the code in seperate script it is working fine as I am passing the filter condition within double inverted comma i.e. "IF", where as I am not able to pass in the same format while I am passing condition in my shiny app as am I calling a function.

Kindly help.I think I am missing a small thing

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use dplyr's `filter()` but you haven't loaded dplyr.

Comment: Its not just mentioned here...now i have added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you are trying to achieve. Where do you define `IF` for example? Is this what you want to do?

```
server <- function(input, output){

  observeEvent(input$action1, { 
    output$view <- renderTable({
      filter(diamonds, diamonds$clarity == input$clarity)
    }) 
  }) 

}
```

Comment: My intention is to provide a table which is a subset of Dimonds and user has a control on which clarity he wants to seee the subset."IF" is a clarity type not any condition. Yes yourcode did work.thanks a lot